# How to handle time-series data in BangDB?

Tags: database, time-series

I realized that [BangDB is a multi-model database including time-series model](https://bangdb.com/product/), but how does it handle timeseries data? It seems [none of its table](https://docs.bangdb.com/table-embedded) is designed to do so.